# Aggregate Transformation vs Sort (remove Duplicate) in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, bids

I'm trying to populate dimension tables on a regular basis and I've thought of two ways of getting distinct values for my dimension:

1. Using an Aggregate transformation and then using the "Group by" operation.
2. Using a Sort transformation while removing duplicates.

I'm not sure which one is better (more efficient), or which one is adopted more widely in the industry.

I tried to perform some tests using dummy data, but I can't quite get a solid answer.

P.S. Using `SELECT DISTINCT` from the source is not an option here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first choice would always be to correct this in my source query if possible. I realise that isn't always an option, but for the sake of completeness for future readers: I would first check whether I had a problem in my source query that was creating duplicates. Whenever a `DISTINCT` seems necessary, I first see whether there's actually a problem with the query that needs resolving.

My second choice would be a `DISTINCT` - if it were possible - because this is one of those cases where it will probably be quicker to resolve in SQL than in SSIS; but I realise that's not an option for you.

From that point, you're getting into a situation where you might need to try out the remaining options. Aside from using an Aggregate or Sort in SSIS, you could also dump the results into a staging table, and then have a separate data flow which does use a `DISTINCT` in its source query. Aggregate and Sort are both blocking transactions in SSIS so using a staging table might end up being faster - but which is fastest for you will depend on a number of factors including the nature of your data, and also the nature of your infrastructure. You might also want to keep in mind what else is running in parallel if you use the SSIS options, as they can be memory-hungry.

If your data is (or can be) sorted in your source or source query, then there's also a clever idea in the link below for creating "semi-blocking" versions of Aggregate and Sort using script tasks:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30703.ssis-implementing-a-faster-distinct-sort-or-aggregate-transformation.aspx

Comment: It's not so much as it is a problem of duplicates in the underlying table, as it is that the nature of the data received from the sources must generate full rows and the underlying database must be denormalized. Thank you for the reply though, it was quite useful to me.

Comment: I loved the source that you had cited. No newer answers were posted by others. Thank you!